# JavaScript naming convention for a "static" class, or module?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, naming-conventions, jsdoc

According to [Google's JavaScript style guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml), classes should begin with a capital letter. However JSDoc supports the use of the [`@static`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-static.html) tag, which asserts that you don't need to instantiate the class to use a member.

I have a class/module that is entirely comprised of static functions and properties.

**Should it be named `namespaceBar.MyFooClass`, or `namespaceBar.myFooClass`?**

Comment: There's no such thing as a "static class" in Javascript. It's simply an *object*.

Comment: @deceze I guess they're talking about things like `Math.xxx()`. It's an object, but it gets used like a class with no instances.

Comment: @Barmar That's why things get really messy when you try to conflate classical inheritance terms with Javascript... If anything, call it a namespace.

Comment: And if you use `Math` as an example, it seems obvious that the convention is to start with a capital.

Comment: Edited the question to be more clear!

Comment: I'd say: whatever works for you, as long as you are consistent. There is no "right" answer. Go with what most other projects in your vendor chain are using. As @Barmar says, if that's just Javascript, `Math` may be the canonical example.

Comment: @deceze The question is about a convention, so the goal is to be consistent with the concensus of other programmers.

Comment: @Barmar Consensus == majority of opinions == opinions == off topic. :)

Comment: Closure-compiler does not recognize or use the JSDoc `@static` annotation. https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/parsing/Annotation.java#L27

Comment: Thanks @ChadKillingsworth, I've edited the question and removed the references to Closure Compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commenter [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29533414/javascript-naming-convention-for-a-static-class-or-module#comment47219959_29533414), if you use `Math` as an example, it seems canonical to capitalise your class/module name even if it will not be instantiated.

A good general guideline appears to be to capitalise a namespace when it provides a single "module" of functionality, "static" or not.

EG.
`myFooNamespace.MyBarClass` - A class that can be instantiated.
`myFooNamespace.MyBazModule` - A "static" class, or module. 
`myFooNamespace.MyBazModule.myBarFoo()` - A function in your module.
`myFooNamespace.MyBazModule.myQuxBaz = "foobar"` - A property in your module.
`myFooNamespace.myQuxNamespace` - A namespace within a namespace.

Answer (score -1):

From my perspective classes and top-level namespaces should start with an upper-case character and variables or functions (which are not constructors of classes) with lower-case. So in your example

```
NamespaceBar.myFooNamespace
```

and as pointed out in the comments I'd tag it as namespace, not as class.

Comment: Not everything Google does is automatically right, but thanks for providing the link.